# MVC 3 Client side validation on jQuery dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-dialog

I am showing lots of form using jquery dialog and I wish to add in client side validation on it. I read through some examples, saying that mvc 3 already somehow support jquery client side validation, but I tried by including the necessary script, and my form like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateFood", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formData" }))
       {
           @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please fix these errors.")
```

When i try to submit my form without fill in the required field, I still dint get any message. Can anyone give me more idea / explanation / examples on this??

Really needs help here... Thanks...

UPDATE (add in the script for my dialog)

```
 $createdialog.dialog("option", "buttons", {
        "Cancel": function () {
            //alert('Cancel');
            $createdialog.dialog('close');

        },
        "Submit": function () {

            var frm = $('#formData');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Food/CreateFood',
                type: 'POST',
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: $createdialog.dialog('close')
            });
        }
    });
```

Once dropped, open dialog:

```
  // Once drop, open dialog to create food
    options.drop = function (event, ui) {
        // Get the ContainerImgName which food dropped at
        var cimg = $(this).attr('id');
        // Pass in ContainerImgName to retrieve respective ContainerID
        // Once success, set the container hidden field value in the FoodForm
        $.ajax({
            url: '/food/getcontainerid',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { cImg: cimg },
            success: function (result) { $('#containerID').val(result); }
        });
        clear();
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($createdialog);
        $createdialog.dialog('open');
    };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've faced the same problem, solved with:

```
 $(name).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: options.witdth,
            heigth: options.height,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            title: options.title,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                // Enable validation for unobtrusive stuffs
                $(this).load(options.url, function () {
                    var $jQval = $.validator;
                    $jQval.unobtrusive.parse($(this));
                });

            }
        });
```

of course you can add the validation on the close event of the dialog, depends on what you're doing, in my case the popup was just for displaying errors so I've performed validation on load of the content. (this pop up is displaying am Action result)

Comment: hi, i tried, but it still doesnt work.. the dialog just close after i click submit eventhough i dint fill in the required field...

Comment: that's strange, in my code, $jQval.unobtrusive.parse($(this)) will add decorations to html elements and bind js validation functions. Are you by chance submitting via AJAX ? Do you see errors in JS Console ? Have you add the @Html.EnableClientValidation(true); somewhere in the view ? Can you post the onclick/onsubmit functions (if you're using 'em) ?

Comment: Hi, actually i m using drag-n-drop, once any item is dropped, i will open the dialog. I had updated my question with the drop option, can help me have a look? really thanks...

Comment: you're submitting with ajax, that's the culprit :). I guess there's a way to trigger the validation even when hijacking' submits with jquery, but haven't found it yet. In this case I prefer to use standard submits with the using Ajax.BeginForm() helper. Just try in your submit function to do a  Form.submit() in js.

Comment: hi, can you show me your submit function?? I dun understand.. really thanks a lot..

Comment: I don't have a function, I just perform plain old form.submit() without jQuery's stuff. In that way validation starts. If you want to hijack form submission, better avoid Ajax.BeginForm and go with plain jQuery solution.

Comment: hi, I just get it works by following the steps here: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/04/30/eagerly-performing-asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-client-side-validation.aspx, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice article, even thou, I usually don't like hacking library scripts directly.

Answer (score 1):

For every dynamically generated form you need to manually run the validator once you inject this content into the DOM as shown in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/03/05/unobtrusive-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) using the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` function.

Comment: Hi, sorry but i not really understand.. so the dom i need to parse by the function is the form? or the dialog? thanks...

Comment: @user834754, this form is not initially in the DOM right? You are inserting it presumably after an AJAX request or something and then showing it in the dialog. It is at the moment you show the dialog that you need to parse.

Comment: Hi, it dint work.. I try to parse the dialog before it open, but I get weird response which once i click submit, the form will be display in a page but no longer in the dialog, any idea?? thanks...

Comment: @user834754, have you AJAXified the form that is inside the jquery dialog? If you don't it will simply perform a normal submit to the server and reload the page.

Comment: I think i know the reason, because there is a try/catch at my controller for the submit action. Is it i doesnt need to have that if i wan to use client side validation at the dialog?? thanks...